# Why the UIButton in UITableViewCell.contentView won't work?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I've did lots of tests and searches and still couldn't find why the `UIButton` that I added into a `UITableViewCell.contentView` won't work. I can guarantee I did everything right, the button still won't answer the `TouchUpInside` event.

code like this won't work:

```
[self.contentView addSubview:theButton];
```

But this would work:

```
[self addSubview:theButton];
```

As you may expected, `self` was a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. and recording to the doc, shouldn't we always add things to `contentView`?

Sorry for my poor English. I hope I described it clearly.

Comment: Does the content view = nil when you add it?

Answer (score 1):

try this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
UIButton *scanQRCodeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
scanQRCodeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260.0f, 6.0f, 45.0f, 25.0f);
scanQRCodeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[scanQRCodeButton setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[cell.contentView addSubview:scanQRCodeButton];
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if your UITableViewCell has a customer height(not the default 44.0f)。
if so, you should set the code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        // add a UIButton that you create
    }
    return cell;
}
```

the reason for this problem is the cell.contentView.size is default (320.f, 44.0f), if your button is over the rect, then the button could not accept the event, so you should set the cell.contentView.frame yourself, like i do the code。

Good Luck。